# Prompt the user

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got stumbled at one exercise from the book Python for everybody could you help me pls?

Exercise 3: Write a program to prompt the user for hours and rate per hour to compute gross pay.

Enter Hours: 35

Enter Rate: 2.75

Pay: 96.25

i wrote that piece of code

```
#compute gross pay
prompt = 'Enter hours\n'
hours = input(prompt)
int(hours)
prompt = 'Enter rate\n'
rate = input(prompt)
int(rate)
pay = hours * rate
print(pay)
```

and i got an error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex2_pay", line 8, in <module>
    pay = hours * rate
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

but i can not figure it out why. I did convert the return value to int

Comment: `int(hours)` doesn't update the value of the `input`. Save `int(hours)` in a variable or instead use `int(input("text"))`

Answer (score 2):

`int(hours)` and `int(rate)` don't actually do anything. You're casting these values to integer types, but ultimately not doing anything with the result. What you probably intended to do was assign them back to their original variables:

```
#compute gross pay
prompt = 'Enter hours\n'
hours = input(prompt)
hours = int(hours)
prompt = 'Enter rate\n'
rate = input(prompt)
rate = int(rate)
pay = hours * rate
print(pay)
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@esqew/JadedBonyAbstractions#main.py)</sup>

However, you should consider making your code a bit more succinct, input tolerant and easier to read by combining a few lines and casting the inputs to `float`s (to handle decimals in addition to integers):

```
#compute gross pay
hours = float(input('Enter hours\n'))
rate = float(input('Enter rate\n'))
print(hours * rate)
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@esqew/JadedBonyAbstractions-1)</sup>

Comment: `int("2.75")` will fail, because it cannot translate it into an integer. I think `float` would actually solve OP's problem.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Great point - I've added that in my secondary "optimized" version of the OP's example.

Comment: It's not an optimization; `int` was never the correct type to use for defining the rate in the first place. (Though when dealing with money, `float` isn't the right type to use either, due to precision issues. `decimal.Decimal` would be more appropriate.)

Answer (score 0):

```
hours = input('Enter hours\n')
hours = int(hours)
rate = input('Enter rate\n')
rate = int(rate)
pay = hours * rate
print(pay)
```

You can simplify your code and fix the `int()`